# ransack+kaminariで可変ページ表示

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

railsで[ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)および[kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari)を使って表示件数(per)を可変に設定できる検索画面を作っております。

[image: 表示件数]
 ↑こちらのセレクトボックスには[20, 50, 100, 500]が入ってます。

`app/controller/items_controller`

```
def index
  @q = Item.ransack(params[:q])
  @items = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(params[:display_number])
end
```

`app/view/items/index.html.slim`

```
- # 検索部分
= search_form_for @q, url: search_items_path, method: :post do |f| 
  = f.text_field :name_cont, :placeholder => '氏名'
  = hidden_field_tag :display_number, params[:display_number]
  = f.submit "エクスポート", :class => "btn btn-default", :id => "csv_dl_submit" if @login_user[:csv_flg]

-# ~~~~略~~~=

-# 表示部分
span 表示件数
  = select_tag :change_display_number, options_for_select([20, 50, 100, 500], params[:display_number]), :class => "form-control input-sm"
  span 件
table
  thead
    tr
      th 氏名
  tbody
    - @items.each do |item|
      tr
        td = web_access.family_name
```

となっており、
表示部分の`:change_display_number`の中身を
検索部分の`params[:display_number]`に渡したいと思います。

`form`タグの中に入っていない`params`はどのように受け渡すのがスマートなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> formタグの中に入っていないparamsはどのように受け渡すのがスマートなのでしょうか?

単純にformタグの中に入れてしまうのが一番シンプルでスマートだと思います。

```
= search_form_for @q, url: search_items_path, method: :post do |f| 
  = f.text_field :name_cont, :placeholder => '氏名'
  = hidden_field_tag :display_number, params[:display_number]
  = f.submit "エクスポート", :class => "btn btn-default", :id => "csv_dl_submit" if @login_user[:csv_flg]

  -# ~~~~略~~~=

  -# 表示部分
  span 表示件数
    = select_tag :display_number, options_for_select([20, 50, 100, 500], params[:display_number]), :class => "form-control input-sm"
    span 件

  -# ~~~~formタグで囲まれるのはここまで~~~=

table
  thead
    tr
      th 氏名
  tbody
    - @items.each do |item|
      tr
        td = web_access.family_name
```

formタグの中に入れられない制約がもしあれば、その理由を詳しく教えてください。

formタグに入れられないのであれば、ボタンクリックのイベントをJavaScriptでフックして、セレクトボックスの選択値をhiddenタグに放り込む、といったやり方が考えられますが、そんなことはせずにformタグに含めてしまう方が断然ラクだと思います。

余談ですが、通常の検索処理はデータの更新を伴わないので、methodはpostではなくgetにするのが一般的です。